# How to change Event Dot Color in FSCalender

Tags: swift3, fscalendar

Here is my code. I am trying to change the dot color but I did not find any solution. Thanks

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {


    return 1;
}
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, eventColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {

        return UIColor.red

}
```

Here is an example image of these event-dots:

[image: Image of the dots in the calender]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend you to have a look at the [this](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/blob/master/Example-Swift/FSCalendarSwiftExample/DelegateAppearanceViewController.swift) it's the example DelegateAppearanceViewController. I believe that i have seen changing the dot color in there. (Atleast there are parameters for the eventDotColors)

Comment: Thank you very much it works fine :)

Comment: I'm kinda impatient, so i added an answer myself :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is taken from [here](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/blob/master/Example-Swift/FSCalendarSwiftExample/DelegateAppearanceViewController.swift). Basically you just use the given method, check for event-type or something like that and return a color of your favour.

```
//Used by one of the example methods
var datesWithEvent = ["2015-10-03", "2015-10-06", "2015-10-12", "2015-10-25"]
var datesWithMultipleEvents = ["2015-10-08", "2015-10-16", "2015-10-20", "2015-10-28"]

//Used in one of the example methods
fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter2: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter
}()
```

The complete example is to long for embedding, so i only took 2 example methods. I added the fields from the example, to have an "complete" example of how such a method could look like.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, eventColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {
     //Do some checks and return whatever color you want to.
     return UIColor.purple  
}

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, eventDefaultColorsFor date: Date) -> [UIColor]? {
    let key = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
    if self.datesWithMultipleEvents.contains(key) {
        return [UIColor.magenta, appearance.eventDefaultColor, UIColor.black]
    }
        return nil
 }
```

For better understanding have a look at linked example class in Github. That example is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: The first method is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do like this:

```
fsCalendar?.appearance.eventDefaultColor = .red
```

Keep coding........: )